# How do variables declared in function treated after the function finishes

Tags: c, memory

I am wondering how is the behavior of memory/variables in following code. Basically i am adding epd_tx_buffer to an array in epd_driver_state by using epd_power_on().

Then these buffers are consumed/used asynchronously via an event driven mechanism. My worry/what i want to know, is whether the content of memory area pointed by "uint8_t * buffer" will be constant or is it possible that it can be overwritten. As epd_power_on finishes and there will be other code executed until async event consumes the buffer.

```
struct epd_tx_buffer {
    uint8_t hasCmd;
    uint8_t * buffer;
    uint16_t bufferLen;
    uint8_t wait_ms;
};

static struct epd_driver_state {
    uint8_t cursor;
    uint8_t length;
    struct epd_tx_buffer buff[256];
    bool isRunning;
} epd_driver_state;

static void epd_power_on(void){
    addToSPIQueueCommandData( ( uint8_t[] ) { POWER_ON }, 1 );
    addToSPIQueueCommandData( ( uint8_t[] ) { PANEL_SETTING, 0x2F }, 2 );
    addToSPIQueueCommandData( ( uint8_t[] ) { PLL_CONTROL, 0x3A }, 2 );
    addToSPIQueueCommandData( ( uint8_t[] ) { POWER_SETTING, 0x03, 0x00, 0x2B, 0x2B, 0x09 }, 6 );
    addToSPIQueueCommandData( ( uint8_t[] ) { BOOSTER_SOFT_START, 0x07, 0x07, 0x17  }, 4);
    addToSPIQueueCommandData( ( uint8_t[] ) { VCM_DC_SETTING_REGISTER, 0x00 }, 2 );
    addToSPIQueueCommandData( ( uint8_t[] ) { VCOM_AND_DATA_INTERVAL_SETTING, 0x47 }, 2 );
}



bool addToSPIQueueCommandData(uint8_t * buffer, uint16_t bufferLen)
{
    if( epd_driver_state.length >= 255 ) return false;
    epd_driver_state.buff[ epd_driver_state.length ].hasCmd         = 1;
    epd_driver_state.buff[ epd_driver_state.length ].buffer         = buffer;
    epd_driver_state.buff[ epd_driver_state.length ].bufferLen      = bufferLen;
    epd_driver_state.length++;
    return true;
}
```

Some explanation will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
addToSPIQueueCommandData( ( uint8_t[] ) { POWER_ON }, 1 );
addToSPIQueueCommandData( ( uint8_t[] ) { PANEL_SETTING, 0x2F }, 2 );
addToSPIQueueCommandData( ( uint8_t[] ) { PLL_CONTROL, 0x3A }, 2 );
addToSPIQueueCommandData( ( uint8_t[] ) { POWER_SETTING, 0x03, 0x00, 0x2B, 0x2B, 0x09 }, 6 );
addToSPIQueueCommandData( ( uint8_t[] ) { BOOSTER_SOFT_START, 0x07, 0x07, 0x17  }, 4);
addToSPIQueueCommandData( ( uint8_t[] ) { VCM_DC_SETTING_REGISTER, 0x00 }, 2 );
addToSPIQueueCommandData( ( uint8_t[] ) { VCOM_AND_DATA_INTERVAL_SETTING, 0x47 }, 2 );
```

These are array compound literals, they will go out of scope once control exits the function. Thus accessing them outside the function using reference is *undefined behavior*.

---

You could consider it doing as below.

```
uint8_t *temp = malloc(sizeof((( uint8_t[] ) { PLL_CONTROL, 0x3A })));
memcpy(temp, (( uint8_t[] ) { PLL_CONTROL, 0x3A }), 2);
addToSPIQueueCommandData(temp, 2);
```

> Note: Make sure you `free` the memory once done processing.

Comment: If the OP has control of function `addToSPIQueueCommandData` then it would make more sense for *it* to make a copy of the array, and also to make whatever arrangements might be needed to free those copies later -- else there's a memory leak.  Alternatively, the OP could create static arrays instead of using compound literals.  In the latter case, it would be safest to make the arrays `const`, and to update the function's signature to accommodate that if needed.

Comment: There is no need to `malloc` constant data that it is known at compile time. It uses more resources than necessary and introduces more potential bugs. Just declare it in a static/global variable as  @JohnBollinger suggested

Comment: @HAL90000 how many such variables you want to declare as op is dealing with asynchronous calls to process them.

Answer (score 0):

Compound literals have automatic storage duration and they stop to exists when you leave the defining block.

Saying it simpler the code shown is a one huge Undefined Behavior

You need to make sure that the lifetime of the object is as long as it is needed. In this case it is not